# Printing a string due to a new line

Tags: c, string, performance, pointers, newline

Is there any **efficient** (- in terms of performance) way for printing some arbitrary string, but only until the first new line character in it (excluding the new line character) ?

---

Example:

```
char *string = "Hello\nWorld\n";

printf(foo(string + 6));
```

Output:

> World

Comment: There certainly is an efficient way. What is the `+ 6` supposed to mean. I actually don't understand what you want. What is the foo function supposed to do ?

Comment: ummmmmmm... `(string + 6)` is same as if you do `&string[6]`, it is providing reference to the `'W'` character in the string. And I think it is not my fault if either of you cannot understand the question as it is ..way beyond understandable.

Comment: So do I unterstand you correctly? You want to print out a `string` up to the first new line character it contains?

Comment: I know what `string+6` means...but I could n't figure out what you are trying to achieve what exactly the `foo` function is supposed to do.

Comment: Well It is an example, so foo does w/e it does to cause the output.
@muXXmit2X You do.

Comment: So actually `printf(foo(string))` should display `Hello` ?

Comment: Should display `World` as it is shown in the question, after "Output:"

Comment: So if you were to call `printf(foo(string));`, Would you expect the output to be `Hello`?   Functionally, your example above is equivalent to `char *string = "World\n";  printf(foo(string));`

Comment: Yes. (but without printing the new line character)

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about performance this might help (untested code):

```
void MyPrint(const char *str)
{
  int len = strlen(str) + 1;
  char *temp = alloca(len);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    char ch = str[i];
    if (ch == '\n')
      break;
    temp[i] = ch;
  }

  temp[i] = 0;

  puts(temp);
}
```

`strlen` is fast, `alloca` is fast, copying the string up to the first `\n` is fast, `puts` is faster than `printf` but is is most likely far slower than all three operations mentioned before together.

Comment: Yes. Nice one. (Btw, isn't memcpy faster than strcpy)

Comment: Maybe `memcpy` is faster then `strcpy` (which I didn't use in my answer BTW), but for `memcpy` you need to know the length to copy and for finding that length you need to scan the string anyway.

Comment: Ahh yes sorry. I somehow managed to see `strcpy` but `strlen` and was hectic to ask.

Comment: Anyway `puts` most likely much slower than copying the string etc., so any difference between `mempy`, `strcpy`etc. won't matter. If you have the source code of `puts` in your environnment you can have a look at that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t writetodelim(char const *in, int delim)
{
  char *end = strchr(in, delim);
  if (!end)
    return 0;
  return fwrite(in, 1, end - in, stdout);
}
```

This can be generalized somewhat (pass the `FILE*` to the function), but it's already flexible enough to terminate the output on any chosen delimiter, including `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Do not use `printf` without format specifier to print a variable string (or from a variable pointer). Use `puts` instead or `"%s", string`.

C strings are terminated by `'\0'` (NUL), not by newline. So, the functions print until the NUL terminator.
You can, however, use your own loop with `putchar`. If that is any performance penalty is to be tested. Normally `printf` does much the same in the library and might be even slower, as it has to care for more additional constraints, so your own loop might very well be even faster.

```
for ( char *sp = string + 6 ; *sp != '\0'; sp++ ) {
    if ( *sp == '\n' )  break;  // newline will not be printed
    putchar(*sp);
}
```

(Move the `if`-line to the end of the loop if you want newline to be printed.)

An alternative would be to limit the length of the string to print, but that would require finding the next newline before calling `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is fast enough, but there is a way to build a string containing the source string up to a new line character only involving one standard function.

```
char *string = "Hello\nWorld\nI love C"; // Example of your string
static char newstr [256]; // String large enough to contain the result string, fulled with \0s or NULL-terimated

sscanf(string + 6, "%s", newstr); // sscanf will ignore whitespaces
sprintf(newstr); // printing the string
```

Comment: Time it. But that will very likely be the slowest version. I think the one in my answer will even be faster than `printf`

Comment: Not in highly-optimized manner I think. It does quite simple operation though and only one format specifier. If it comes to caching, I don't know if it will be significantly slower than your straightforward approach.

Comment: Now noticed you are printing each character separately.. it might be logically faster as it doesn't involve `printf` but it might be quite the opposite. Sadly I am not good in measuring.

Comment: Malina, I will not discuss further. I think I can very well estimate run-time of software after doing programming on verious levels, architectures, etc. for more than 30 years now. However, you are welcome to **prove** me wrong! (btw: how do you think `printf` prints the single chars of a string actually?)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't care of anyone's educational level, years of experience or title as long as THEY prove that their approach is faster than the one I (sadly) discovered.

Comment: Youz are behaving childish. "But I want it to be faster! **stomp on floor**". I did not say your version is faster (parsing a format string, then the input string, the parsing another format string for printf. Even `printf("%s", s)` would be faster.

Comment: ... I just provided speed as an important factor. Speed truly matters in some cases with heavy programs, where you need to spare resources.. But you already know that, you are programming for over 30 years.

Comment: Printing to console to bre read by a user? surely, you can read more than 25 frames/s of text output.

Comment: I am not quite convinced in that. Even if your version is slightly faster than mine, what if one decides NOT to print the string or at least not to print it like that ? Because I am not an expert, but I think it is good if the method one provides covers the needs, but is best if it does even more / can be used widely.

Comment: Huh?? If you do not want to print, then why use printf? Sorry, I'm out of this discussion; not in the mood for kindergarten.

Comment: Watch your words. I might be acting "childish" but you are the one actually offending. I didn't said I don't want to print. I am saying that your method would be more majority user useful if it builds a string, not just print each character separately.

Comment: Feeling offended is much diffeerent from being offending. As you acknowledge yourself what I stated, that cannot be offending. EOM

Comment: I do feel offended. And all I wanted is a proof that your version is actually faster, especially without the `putchar`, but with building a string. Otherwise it might be faster, but certainly not that useful (thoroughly to others).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no more efficient way than simply looping over your string until you find the first `\n` in it. As Olaf mentioned it, a string in C ends with a terminating `\0` so if you want to use `printf` to print the string you need to make sure it contains the terminating `\0` or yu could use `putchar` to print the string character by character.

If you want to provide a function creating a string up to the first found new line you could do something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 256

void foo(const char* string, char *ret) 
{
  int len = (strlen(string) < MAX) ? (int) strlen(string) : MAX;
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) 
  {
    if (string[i] == '\n') break;
    ret[i] = string[i];
  }
  ret[i + 1] = '\0';
}


int main()
{
  const char* string = "Hello\nWorld\n";
  char ret[MAX];
  foo(string, ret);
  printf("%s\n", ret);
  foo(string+6, ret);
  printf("%s\n", ret);
}
```

This will print

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: That loops multiple times on the string. Note that `printf` itself uses `putchar`, but with more overhead (widht-field, etc) in the loop and outside (format parsing).

Comment: Yes you're right but that way you can povide a string wich can be manipulated outside of `foo()`. And you can also use this function for GUI interfaces for example and not just for printing at `stdout`. It is just a little bit more flexible to use.

Comment: Ok. OP just did not ask for than, but emphasised speed. But according to comments change mind in-between (without updating the answer). Whereas I do not see much gain, as that is a trivial loop anyway. Or just use `strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

Another **fast** way (if the new line character is truly unwanted)
Simply:

```
*strchr(string, '\n') = '\0';
```